# How to add React to html using modern features

Tags: reactjs

I have been tasked to add a react component to a website that is currently a html page and an empty main.js file.

How would I go about creating a react component within my script that allows use of modern feature etc like `useState` and `useEffect`?

On the official docs there is a 2 year old article which relies on components rather than hooks.

Comment: Presumably if you're able to ingest and use React v16.8 or newer then you can create React functional components and use React hooks. That being said, there's nothing wrong really with still writing and using class-based components. What have you tried already?

Comment: I have script tags for React in my HTML but I have no idea how to consume them and display a React component in this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you add React and ReactDOM to your HTML page:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

you can simply render a React component to the existing HTML page like:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <MyComponent test={true} />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

where `container` is the `id` of element your React component should be rendered within.

Comment: Thanks. How would I use useState etc?

Comment: Just updated the answer. Basically you can render a React component like this, and inside your React component file you can use the React features. Note that if you want to use JSX you need a built setup that converts it to plain JavaScript